# Scientific notation in axis plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have this plot, with a very large scale for both `x` and `y` axes:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/layers/altorder/.define layer set={
        axis background,axis grid,main,axis ticks,axis lines,axis tick labels,
        axis descriptions,axis foreground
    }{/pgfplots/layers/standard},
}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,
             xmin=-1e12, xmax=2e12,
             ymin=-5e23, ymax=2e24,
             axis line style = thin,
             axis lines=middle,
             axis line style={-{Stealth[length=2.5mm]}},
             thick,
             y tick label style={/pgf/number format/sci},
             x tick label style={/pgf/number format/sci,
                    rotate=45,
                    anchor=east},
             grid=major, grid style={dashed,gray!30},
             set layers=altorder]

    \addplot[draw=blue,thick,restrict y to domain={-5e23:2e24}] {x};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I tried using `label style={/pgf/number format/sci}` but the result is not exactly what I was expecting:

[image]

Instead of being respectively in the upper left and the lower right, I would like that 10^24 and 10^12 were along the axes (respectively `y` and `x`), besides each tick, instead of 10^0 and 10^{-1}, which do not make sense.

How to accomplish this requirement?

---

As requested, the code has been updated: now it is a MWE. It tries to plot `x`, but it actually doesn't show anything. It anyway shows the issue about the tick labels. The suggestion in the [linked answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183411/74786) has already been applied to obtain oblique tick labels.

Comment: Could you make an example that doesn't rely on files we don't have (`test.tex`), and which includes all the necessary libraries? Preferably a complete example, that can be copied and compiled without any modifications.

Comment: That said, `scaled ticks=false` (e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9803) and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183411/ perhaps for 2.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I updated my question, providing a working example. Thank you. With `scaled ticks=false` it works. If you want, you can write an answer.